# hover на блок после добавления нового класса

Tags: jquery, hover

Вопрос в следующем: после добавления блоку класса, hover на этот новый класс не работает. Например у меня есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

и код jquery

```
$('.block1').on('click', function(){
    $('.wrap').addClass('on')
    $(this).fadeOut()
})

$('.on').hover(function(){
    $('.block2').fadeIn()
    $('.block2').fadeOut()
})
```

он добавляет класс on блоку и скрывает block1, но далее при наведении на on ничего не происходит. Кто-нибудь подскажите в чём проблема. Пытался гуглить на англ. и ничего подобного не нашёл. Также если ставить ховер например на wrap то он работает, но на только что добавленный класс - нет.

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #121212;
}

.block1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

.block2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.block1').on('click', function(){
    $('.wrap').addClass('on')
    $(this).fadeOut()
})
```

Вариант 1:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.on' function(){
    $('.block2').fadeIn()
    $('.block2').fadeOut()
});
```

Описан [здесь](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) (http://joxi.ru/l2ZKjjRf8nR7VA)

Вариант 2:

```
$('.block').hover(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('on')) {
    $('.block2').fadeIn()
    $('.block2').fadeOut()
}
})
```

Проблема в том, что .hover вешает событие сразу на все элементы, у которых есть класс `.on` , а тебе нужно назначить событие "на будущее", через jQuery функцию `.on()`

Comment: вариант 3 - добавить событие сразу после добавления класса

Comment: большое спасибо)